# Random number file writer and read

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Instructions

Write a program that writes a series of random numbers to a file.

1. The count of numbers to be generated for each execution will be
   randomly between 1 and 20.
2. The actual numbers generated will be random integers between 1 and
   100
3. Each run of the program will display a message indicating the
   number of new numbers written to the file
4. Each run of the program will display a message indicating the
   number of records read from the file
5. You cannot count or assume to know how many records are in the
   file. Use the deadline method with a loop to `EOF`.
6. Your file read and file write must each be functions (2 functions,
   one for each), and each be called from main.
7. You must use `w` mode for the first write to the file and `a` or
   `w` mode for each time after.
8. User will determine whether to append to existing file or write new
   file.

### Here's what I have

```
import random

def main():
        more = 'y'

        while more.lower() == 'y':

                random_numbers = open('Unit 4 numbers.txt', 'w')
                NumtoBeWr = random.randint(1, 20)
                print(NumtoBeWr, 'numbers added to output file: ')

                for count in range(NumtoBeWr):
                      number = random.randint(1, 100)
                      print(number)
                      random_numbers.write(str(number) + '\n')

                random_numbers.close()

                random_numbers = open('Unit 4 numbers.txt', 'r')


                # This the code to read the file

                line = random_numbers.readline()
                number = 0
                total = 0

                while line != " ":
                        number = int(line)

                        line = line.rstrip('\n')
                        print(number)
                        total = total + int(line)
                        number = number + number
                        line = random_numbers.readline()

                        print("The total of the numbers: "+ str (total))
                        print("Total count of numbers read from file: "+ str (number))
                        more = input("Do you want to run again to write and read more numbers. (Y/N): ")
                random_numbers.close()

        print("Thank for using this program")


main()
```

### A few problems I an having

1. It's not adding all the number together
2. It's not counting all the number together

Sample output for the finish program should look like this:

[image: Sample output for the finish program should look like this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `while` loop as follows:

```
while line:
    number += int(line)
    total += 1
    line = random_numbers.readline().rstrip("\n")

print("The total of the numbers: " + str(total))
print("Total count of numbers read from file: " + str(number))
more = input("Do you want to run again to write and read more numbers. (Y/N): ")
```

That is, you should put the printing of the total counts outside of the loop. Furthermore, you should increment `total` by one instead of by the number in the current line to get the total numbers generated.

Comment: I have update the while loop and it's adding the number them together and also counting them. But how it's not counting the old number to the new number when I enter "y" for it to "write and read more numbers". My question here is, how do you get it to count the old number with the new number ever time when you enter "y for it to write and read more number". Like the one from the sample file. first it added 52, and the second time it print the 52 and added 39 and said total number read from file is 2.

Comment: Put the initializations (assignments to `0`) outside the first `while` loop.

Comment: Hey, I did what you told me, but it's not working. I have assignment number to 0 and total too, but still it's not writing and reading the old number to the new number. Instead if I enter 'y', it just write and read the number number and does't include the old number with the number number or even count them with the new number. Can you pleas show me how to do it, please?